# How do I get typescript to stop complaining about functions it doesn't know about?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using Typescript for a web app that needs to use the JavaScript full screen API. The full screen API isn't officially supported yet, so you have to use vendor prefixes. Here's my code, based on the sample from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Toggling_fullscreen_mode):

```
function toggleFullScreen(element: JQuery) {
    var fs = element[0];
    if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
        if (fs.requestFullscreen) {
            fs.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (fs.msRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (fs.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            fs.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (fs.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

However in my IDE (Visual Studio, but this would happen anywhere), I get errors like:

```
The property 'fullscreenElement' does not exist on value of type 'Document'.
The property 'mozFullScreenElement' does not exist on value of type 'Document'.
The property 'webkitFullscreenElement' does not exist on value of type 'Document'.
```

Of course TypeScript can't know that these functions exist, but nor do I want to re-declare document as `any` just to get rid of these errors, because then I'll lose all the other type hints.

What is the solution here? How do I get TypeScript to stop complaining but keep as many type annotations as I can?

Comment: Perhaps create a [`.d.ts` file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files)? (Or in this specific case, find one someone else has already created -- and if not, share the one you do...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simplistically, you could add those items to the `Document` interface and the errors would go away.

```
interface Document {
    exitFullscreen: any;
    mozCancelFullScreen: any;
    webkitExitFullscreen: any;
    fullscreenElement: any;
    mozFullScreenElement: any;
    webkitFullscreenElement: any;
}
```

You could add full type information for each of these, even the simple:

```
interface Document {
    exitFullscreen: () => void;
    mozCancelFullScreen: () => void;
    webkitExitFullscreen: () => void;
    fullscreenElement: () => void;
    mozFullScreenElement: () => void;
    webkitFullscreenElement: () => void;
}
```

This would prevent them being mis-used.

For static properties, you may just need to make the type dynamic, the important part in the example below is the type assertion on `Element`, i.e. `(<any>Element)`:

```
fs.webkitRequestFullscreen((<any>Element).ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

Answer (score 29):

I have the same problem. Just use 'Square bracket' notation to solve it.

```
 if (document['exitFullscreen']) {
    document['exitFullscreen']();
 } else if (document['webkitExitFullscreen']) {
    document['webkitExitFullscreen']();
 } else if (document['mozCancelFullScreen']) {
    document['mozCancelFullScreen']();
 } else if (document['msExitFullscreen']) {
    document['msExitFullscreen']();
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Nor does:

```javascript
if ("webkitExitFullscreen" in document) {
   document.webkitExitFullscreen();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the answer of [Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25994697/3950519) we added some details to these types and declared them in a regular TypeScript Module with imports/exports. This means you also have to declare the global namespace:

```
declare global {
  interface Document {
    mozCancelFullScreen?: () => Promise<void>;
    msExitFullscreen?: () => Promise<void>;
    webkitExitFullscreen?: () => Promise<void>;
    mozFullScreenElement?: Element;
    msFullscreenElement?: Element;
    webkitFullscreenElement?: Element;
  }

  interface HTMLElement {
    msRequestFullscreen?: () => Promise<void>;
    mozRequestFullscreen?: () => Promise<void>;
    webkitRequestFullscreen?: () => Promise<void>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added these codes to global.d.ts under src folder, however, it still continue giving error.

Comment: The correct name for the Mozilla function is mozRequestFullScreen with a capital S.

Answer (score 2):

Steve fenton's answer is excellent and in the long run that is what you *should* do. Remember Types are documentation and will help the next developer.

## Bad but proving that typescript is permissive if you want it to be

Purely as a thought experiment you can create a local variable to shadow the global one and *explicitly* type it to be *any* only once:

```
function toggleFullScreen(element: JQuery) {
    var document:any = window.document;
    document.AnythingCanHappen = 123; // No error 
}
```

And for more fancy ones (grab from an outer scope):

```
var Element_Copy=Element; 
function toggleFullScreen(element: JQuery) {
    var Element:any = Element_Copy; 
    Element.ShootMyself = true;
}
```

Complete example:

```
var Element_Copy=Element;                         // Magic
function toggleFullScreen(element: JQuery) {
    var document:any = window.document;           // Magic
    var Element:any = Element_Copy;               // Magic
    var fs = element[0];
    if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
        if (fs.requestFullscreen) {
            fs.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (fs.msRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (fs.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            fs.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (fs.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today and the solutions that I've seen here did not completely work on our angular 7 project.

Here is what we've done to make it work.
We've first created an interface for Document as mentioned above. (we only needed 'fullscreenElement' in our case, but you can add any you like).

```
export interface Document extends HTMLDocument {
    fullscreenElement: any;
}
```

Imported this into our component without implementing it.

```
import { Document } from '../interfaces/document';
```

Then, instead of using `document.fullscreenElement` you can cast `document` to the expanded type we created above, like this:

```
(document as Document).fullscreenElement
```

This allowed us to make a fullscreen change detector like this:

```
@HostListener('document:fullscreenchange', ['$event']) onfullscreenchange(e) {
  if ((document as Document).fullscreenElement) {
    this.isFullscreen = true;
  } else {
    this.isFullscreen = false;
  }
}
```

Typescript will now accept these newly defined properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can just cast to "any" before accessing the properties and functions.

Example:

```
if ((<any> canvas).mozRequestFullScreen) {
    (<any> canvas).mozRequestFullScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not recommended** but another solution to stop the compiler complaining:

```
const document: any = window.document;
```

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: By side stepping TypeScript you side step the benefits of type safety. There are all sorts of cases where things could slip through the compiler by making them `any`. The general expectation is to try to find the strict way of expressing something but you'll plenty of cases in production where developers don't have the patience or experience and just take "the easy way".