# IDE acknowledges that variable exists, but Typescript gives comiler error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, html5-canvas

Visual studio code provides code completion for and doesn't give a warning/error for my typescript code, but when compiling it from the command line with `tsc fullscreen.ts`, TypeScript gives an error message

my code: `fullscreen.ts`

```
function checkFullscreen() {
    if (document.fullscreenElement !== null) {
        console.log("There is a fullscreen element");
    }
    else {
        console.log("There is no fullscreen element");
    }
}
```

compiler error:

```
fullscreen.ts:2:18 - error TS2339: Property 'fullscreenElement' does not exist on type 'Document'.
```

This is what I found in `/usr/share/code-oss/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` using VS Code's go to definition

```
interface Document extends Node, GlobalEventHandlers, ParentNode, DocumentEvent {
...
    readonly fullscreenElement: Element | null;
...
}
```

where ellipses represent irrelevant lines of code. Clearly TypeScript interfaces exist to check my code, but for some reason the TypeScript compiler can't find them.

For context, this is html that I am trying to work with

`fullscreen.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="fullscreen" onClick="checkFullscreen()">Check Fullscreen</button>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="fullscreen.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

These are the only two files in my directory -- no tsconfig, node_modules, etc. And just in case it is useful, here is my typescript version

```
tsc --version
Version 3.3.3
```

etid:[documentation for this api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#Properties_included_from_DocumentOrShadowRoot)

Comment: In the bottom right corner of VS Code, what language mode do you see there? Does it say TypeScript? My guess right now is that it says JavaScript and that you need to change the language mode to TypeScript.

Comment: VS Code says it is TypeScript in the bottom corner.

Comment: After restarting the language server, I still get 0 "Problems" in VS Code and the same 1 compile error.

When doing this I noticed that the typescript version in the bottom of my window was 3.0.3, not the 3.3.3 of the command line.

Comment: Right.. it isn't VSCode, its that you need to pass the right arguments to `tsc`. I'm looking into which ones you need right now.

Comment: What TypeScript version is VS Code using? That is also in the bottom right corner of the VS Code window. It appears that the fullscreen API worked in 3.0 but does not work in 3.3. I.e. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to TypeScript [around version 3.3 broke the fullscreen support.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28681)

Your VS Code is probably using an older TypeScript version that supports the fullscreen API. The bottom right of VS Code shows its TypeScript version.

**Two possible solutions:**

1. add your own type definitions [as this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25994697/1108891) or
2. downgrade your command line's TypeScript version with `npm install -g typescript@3.0`.